# Execute commands with notepad++

Tags: command, notepad++

How can I specify the actual file to process using the Run command in Notepad++.
I want for example run pdflatex using the actualfile as input, or the cs compiler, etc. 
Using the entire path isn't practical, it must works with any actual file.

Comment: Could you please expand a bit on your approach. I am interested in setting up Notepad++ properly. Thanks

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can automatically add the current file using a variable in the execution string:

```
C:\temp\test.exe "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

The list of available variables is documented [here](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/config-files/#userdefinedcommands). Examples:

- FULL_CURRENT_PATH = `E:\My Web\main\welcome.html`
- CURRENT_DIRECTORY = `E:\My Web\main`
- FILE_NAME = `welcome.html`
- NAME_PART = `welcome`
- EXT_PART = `.html`
- SYS.`<var>` e.g.: SYS.PATH = `%PATH%`
- CURRENT_WORD = `<selection or word under cursor>`
- CURRENT_LINESTR = `<text of the line line under cursor>`
- CURRENT_LINE = `<line number>`
- CURRENT_COLUMN = `<column number>`
- NPP_DIRECTORY = `c:\Program Files\notepad++`
- NPP_FULL_FILE_PATH = `c:\Program Files\notepad++\notepad++.exe`

You can also see the source code at RunDlg.cpp [line 77](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/blob/06db9ee338ac9659b01b960325486a1791b249b0/PowerEditor/src/WinControls/StaticDialog/RunDlg/RunDlg.cpp#L77) and [line 26](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/blob/93a9962fdea155552fc9f08d09b729ecf7d9073a/PowerEditor/src/WinControls/StaticDialog/RunDlg/RunDlg.h#L26)

Comment: Is there a way to get several open files in Npp to run a compare program for example?

Comment: NPP should have this list or a link to the docs in the Run... dialog.

Comment: @sinsedrix You could have a "Mark for comparison" command that saves the file path to some environment variable like `%NPP_COMPARE%` and a second command like "Diff with marked" that would do `diff "$(SYS.NPP_COMPARE)" "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"`

Comment: Btw using this with [HxD](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) is a great way to add Hex Editor support to NPP.

Comment: `EXT_PART` actually _includes_ the dot; it should be `.html` here. (Edit queue is full :/ )

Comment: @BenPhilipp That makes sense, I have updated my answer. Thanks for pointing that out.