# How to run cmd scripts with notepad or notepad++

Tags: cmd, notepad

I have absolutely no idea on how to run cmd scripts using notepad. I want to be able to automatically run a cmd script as my user logs on to my computer. I researched everywhere, but could not find anything that could help. All i really want is some stater code to work off of so that I can input my own scripts. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614608/execute-commands-with-notepad

Comment: how about the autostart folder? I think, it's built for this kind of Tasks.